# HTML5 Range dynamic creation via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, slider, range

I am trying to create [dynamic HTML5 range input](http://webhole.net/2010/04/24/html-5-slider-input-tutorial/)  to control volume in my game.

The idea is to have it over my canvas.

Here is what the code looks like :

```
    var slider = document.createElement('input');
    slider.id = "volume";
    slider.type = 'range';
    slider.min = 0;
    slider.max = 1;
    slider.value = 0.5;
    slider.step = 0.1;
    document.body.appendChild(slider);
```

The slider appears, but not the good way. On chrome, just the cursor appears and not the entire slider, and I can't move it. On the inspector the element exist and is okay.

```
    <input id="volume" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1"> on chrome
```

On firefox, it just doesn't appear.

```
<input id="volume" type="range"> on firefox
```

So I'm just wondering why my slider doesn't appear correctly. Is there anything I'm doing wrong ?

PS : I already tried modifying node orders or zIndex and stuff like that.

Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe, `input type="range"` just doesn't supported in FireFox?

Comment: Oh you're right. I just tried creating a firefox test file and the range didn't work... But still, the result I get on chrome of the slider not appearing entirely is pretty strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works correctly in chrome. Consider this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/webdevel/Qmvam/

It might happens if you are trying to create element dynamically before DOM is ready.

Firefox doesnt support it yet.

Comment: It doesn't work. It loads everything except the value, that is for some strange reason omited.